# Excluding results from an SQL query only if both conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, one storing date range starting from today (2021-04-22) until today+5 and second one with deliveries and products. I need to return all `delivery_id`'s which are in the range of `dates` table excluding `"CUSTOM"` products **only** if the `deliveries.end_date` is equal to today (so `A01` should be included, but `A02` should be excluded). Currently it excludes everything `"CUSTOM"`.

The output should include following columns:

```
datess | delivery_id | product
```

Tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE dates 
(
  datess DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO dates(datess)
VALUES
('2021-04-22 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-23 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-24 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-25 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-26 00:00:00.000'),
('2021-04-27 00:00:00.000')


CREATE TABLE deliveries 
(
  delivery_id VARCHAR(20),
  product VARCHAR(10),
  start_date DATETIME,
  end_date DATETIME,
);
INSERT INTO deliveries(delivery_id, product, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
('A01', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-23'),
('A02', 'CUSTOM', '2021-04-21', '2021-04-22'),
('A03', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-30'),
('A04', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-24'),
('A05', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-19', '2021-04-22'),
('A06', 'NORMAL', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-20')
```

Here is the select I have:

```
    declare @TodaysDate    datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + '00:00:00.000'
    declare @EndDate      datetime = dateadd(day,5,@TodaysDate)
    declare @TomorrowsDate      datetime = dateadd(day,1,@TodaysDate)
    
    select dt.datess, de.delivery_id, de.product from dates dt left join deliveries de
    on dt.datess between de.start_date and de.end_date
    and (de.end_date <> @TodaysDate AND de.product NOT LIKE '%CUSTOM%')
    
    order by delivery_id
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also be clear on the rows you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to return all delivery_id's which are in the range of dates table excluding "CUSTOM" products only if the deliveries.end_date is equal to today (so A01 should be included, but A02 should be excluded).

I am not sure what the first part of the condition means.  But you can handle the rest using this logic:

```
select d.*
from deliveries d
where not (d.product = 'CUSTOM' and d.end_date = (select min(da.datess) from dates da));
```

If I understand the first, you could use:

```
select d.*
from deliveries d
where not (d.product = 'CUSTOM' and d.end_date = (select min(da.datess) from dates da)) or
      (d.product <> 'CUSTOM' and
       d.start_date in (select da.datess from dates da) and
       d.end_date in (select da.datess from dates da)
      );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=456a4c6311f760c11b4ea811a7fe258e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That works, thanks for help. I wasn't very clear with my description, but in the output I would need following columns: datess | delivery_id | product